# Gitlab markdown: italics in code with a language specifier

Tags: gitlab, markdown

In **Gitlab**, is there any way to include italics inside code with a language specifier? I'd like to produce something like

```bash
$ echo "hello world"
```

In Gitlab I know I can use a language specifier such as

````
``` bash
$ echo "hello world"
```
````

and I can incorporate italics with

```
<pre>$ echo "<i>hello world</i>"</pre>
```

But how do I combine the two? I've tried doing something like this:

```
<pre lang="bash">$ echo "<i>hello world</i>"</pre>
```

which correctly formats the italics but doesn't provide colorization.

Comment: You would simply provide some different styles in your CSS. Determine which ever styling hook for quoted strings and add some CSS which causes them to be italic. Or do you want to only have the one item italic, not all quoted strings? That is probably not possible. Some syntax highlighters provide a highlight option, but that is usually for an entire line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just want to designate some text as italic, but it doesn't necessary have to be in a quote. Another example: <pre>$ cp doc.txt <i>new_file.txt</i></pre>

Comment: Then you will need to use your own custom raw HTML. There are no tools which will do that for you.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you think you could provide a simple example? I don't have experience with HTML.

Comment: The examples in your question are as good as it gets.

Comment: Is there a way to manually colorize them?

Comment: You could run your code through your syntax highlighter first. That would add the various style hooks to colorize it. Then copy the raw HTML output by the syntax highlighter and paste that into your Markdown document. Then you could add your `<i>` tags to italicize whatever you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but couldn't get it to show color. If someone has a working example, that'd be great.